# Facebook Page Tab App only shows up for users that are logged into Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I know there are a bunch of questions similar to this but none actually answer my question. The issue is not being caused by sandbox mode, http vs https, or admin user status.

I've created a page tab app that is live and can be viewed and used by any user that is logged into Facebook.

However when not logged into Facebook, a person can still see the page but the app doesn't appear on the page, only the photos, likes, and events page tabs appear.

Is this the default/only way Facebook handles third-party page tab apps, or is there a method of setting it up so people can view the app even when not logged into Facebook?

The app doesn't use any of a facebook users data, and is really just a method displaying and purchasing products via Facebook.

Comment: do you have any country/user restrictions?

Comment: Just that users be from the US.  That might be it.

Comment: That is definitely it.

Comment: What if I don't have any restrictions set? I'm having the exact same problem (not in sandbox mode, no HTTP vs HTTPS issues, etc) and I just can't get the page tab to show for anonymous users. What other things can impact the tab visibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the APP > Settings > Advanced page of your Facebook app, there are country restrictions.
This requires that you have the Facebook user information, meaning the app can't be used unless the user is logged in.

I had 'United States' as a restriction, just because our primary user base would be from the US.  I removed the restriction and now it appears for people that aren't logged into Facebook.

I'm not positive but I believe any of the restrictions in this area being set would lead to the user having to log into see the app.